# Audio/Video Capture in PhoneGap/Cordova using external Java plugin

Tags: java, javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am developing an android application using PhoneGap/cordova and Javascript. I want to include audio/video capturing functionality in a particular html Div of my application using external Java plugin.

Or some mechanism where I can have a native Java based widget which will come in the same screen at a particular location (rather than replacing the current view completely and occupying the entire screen)

I have searched across the web but could not find an efficient way to do it. Can anyone suggest me any way to handle this?

Comment: My expierence using the camera with cordova has proven difficult. I fear this won't be possible without native development. However, if you find a solution, you should answer it here yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to use the built-in feature?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this blog,hope will be helpful

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you want: Instead of DIV use overlay android fragment.

CordovaWebView is part of an Android activity. That means we can overlay a fragment or say dialog at a location we want. Similar to native android development.

Challenge: If you want to show DIV/Dialog in between HTML you will have to take care of lot of positioning related issue.

Solution: You can target to have your DIV/Dialog positioned at the start or end and can then re-position your HTML placeholders.

Things you would require: Cordova Plugin creation, Dialog/Fragment understanding, JavaScript to reposition the DOM elements (if required), Then all is native.

[Here is a SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035756/can-an-android-fragment-overlaying-the-phonegap-activity) which can help you.

Please let us know if it helps and it would be great if you share your end solution.